# Dynamically add array elements to select options without duplicates

Tags: javascript, html

I have this drop-down menu. My goal is to transfer the elements of an array as choices on the drop-down menu. However, I want repeating array elements to be copied to the drop-down only once. I'm looking for transferring my array to another array without repetition. So, I can rather use that new array to transfer its element to the drop-down menu. For example, on the drop-down menu, the "kg" and "lbs" would only exist once instead of twice.

```js
amountType = document.getElementById("amount-type");

arr = ["kg", "medium", "lbs", "liter", "kg", "small", "lbs"];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = arr[i];
  el.value = arr[i];
  
  amountType.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id="amount-type"></select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

First you can find the unique elements from the array using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
var amountType = document.getElementById("amount-type");

var arr = ["kg", "medium", "lbs", "liter", "kg", "small", "lbs"];
arr = [...new Set(arr)]; //get the unique elements
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = arr[i];
  el.value = arr[i];
  
  amountType.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id="amount-type"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the option with the current value. If an option exists with that value, the length of the array returned from `querySelectorAll` will be greater or equal to 1.

```js
amountType = document.getElementById("amount-type");

arr = ["kg", "medium", "lbs", "liter", "kg", "small", "lbs"];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (amountType.querySelectorAll('option[value="' + arr[i] + "\"]").length == 0) {
    let el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = arr[i];
    el.value = arr[i];
    amountType.appendChild(el);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="amount-type"></select>
```